# THE HUNGRY FISH problem: Infected Fish can eat another fish having size less that its own. Minimum number of operation required

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, backtracking

> An evil scientist has developed an injection that induces insatiable
> hunger in a fish. On giving this injection, a fish of size **x** can
> eat another fish of smaller size **y (y < x)** and become a fish of
> size **x + y** retaining this hunger. An aquarium has a number of
> fishes of various sizes. The scientist introduces an injected fish
> into this aquarium with an objective that eventually *only 1 fish
> remains*. In order to achieve this, the scientist is allowed only two
> types of moves: either add a normal fish of any size or remove an
> existing normal fish from the aquarium. Given the sizes of other
> fishes in the aquarium and the size of injected fish, write a program
> to determine the minimum number of moves needed by the scientist to
> achieve his objective. For example, suppose there are **5** fishes in
> the aquarium, the injected fish is of size **10** and the other fishes
> are of sizes **9, 20, 25,** and **100**. To ensure that only **1**
> fish remains in the aquarium the scientist needs to remove the fish of
> size **100** and add a fish of size **3**. So the output is **2**. The
> sequence of steps is shown below. The sizes of fishes in the aquarium
> at each step are shown in curly braces. The highlighted number is the
> size of the injected fish.
>
> **Input format**: {infectedFish} # {a,b,c,d ... } where a,b,c etc are normal fishes
>
> **Example:**
>
> - 10#9,20,25,100 ===> 2
> - 3#25,20,100,400,500 ===> 5
> - 50#25,20,9,100 ===>0

I have used following code to solve the problem:

```
def hungryfish(arr):

    ans, result = 0, []
    minimummoves(arr, ans, result)
    return min(result)

def minimummoves(arr, ans, result):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        result.append(ans)
        return
    if arr[0] > arr[1]:
        minimummoves([arr[0] + arr[1]] + arr[2:], ans, result)
    if arr[0] <= arr[1]:
        if arr[0]!=1:
            minimummoves([arr[0] + arr[0] - 1 ] + arr[1:], ans + 1, result)
        minimummoves([arr[0]] + arr[2:], ans + 1, result)

arr = [10,9,20,25,100]
print(hungryfish(arr))
```

Will the above code passes all the edge test cases, If so any improvements can be done?

Can we use dynamic programming for this problem?

Comment: You have asked 3 questions. Please ask only one question.

Comment: Did you possibly mean 'any improvements'...?

Comment: Yes, the input can be unsorted @DavidEisenstat

Comment: New to stackoverflow 
Next time I will follow it
@trincot

Comment: yes, I meant 'any improvements' so that the code could be simpler
edited the question after the comment of @CiaPan
thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Did you run your code on test cases? Did it solve them correctly? Or may be you verified the cases quoted in your question, but you're curious if there are some cases not tested by those three...?

Comment: I framed my own test cases and the code solved them correctly, the test cases that are in the question came with the question itself which my code solved them correctly.
I am looking for the test cases that my code may fail but i did not find any, and I also think that I need not use the "result" array that is O(n) space and it can be done in O(1) space complexity but I am not able to do it. @CiaPan

Answer (score 3):

To expand on my comment:

In all optimal solutions, if we remove a non-infected fish, then we remove all non-infected fish not smaller than that fish. Otherwise, the infected fish could just eat the fish that we removed after the fish that we didn't remove.

There exists an optimal solution where, whenever the infected fish can eat the smallest other fish, that action is next. The proof is by induction and repeatedly modifying any optimal solution by inserting the eat action and deleting the corresponding eat or remove (actually just eat, but it's more work to prove that) action later in the sequence.

By the same token, there exists an optimal solution that satisfies the above criterion such that, whenever the infected fish eats a fish that we added, the latter fish should be one smaller than the former.

This leads to the following O(n log n)-time algorithm (O(n) if the input is already sorted):

```py
def hungry_fish(infected, others):
    others = sorted(others)
    best = len(others)
    added = 0
    for i, other in enumerate(others):
        while infected <= other:
            added += 1
            if added >= best:
                return best
            infected += infected - 1
        infected += other
        removed = len(others) - (i + 1)
        best = min(best, added + removed)
    return best


print(hungry_fish(10, [9, 20, 25, 100]))
print(hungry_fish(3, [25, 20, 100, 400, 500]))
print(hungry_fish(50, [25, 20, 9, 100]))
```